# Input-Digits-Image is not recognised correctly using Tensorflow's MNIST dataset

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to do handwriting character recognition using Tensorflow in Google-colab.

I have trained and tested model with an accuracy of 91%

I tried it on image given in the tutorial, and it worked correctly.
it was 28*28 resized.

[image: screenshot] 
When I wanted to try it on my input-image, it is predicting wrong results as 2,3, but my input-image is of 'digit-6'.

the problem may be in image-operations and before passing to model.

[image: screenshot]

also, further I wanted to pass that image for realtime-recognition.
I am doing resizing, inverting of the image, to make it compatible with my trained labels.
OpenCV input image is represented opposite-notation of tensorflow labels, as the current matrix represents black as 0 and white as 255.

my [GitHub Jupyter-notebook file](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/Google-colab-hcr/blob/master/demoHCR.ipynb) is followed from [tutorial of digitalocean's blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-neural-network-to-recognize-handwritten-digits-with-tensorflow)

How can I upload an image taken from a phone/webcam and recognize characters from that image?
where I am making mistakes in processing image?

further, I wanted to pass that image in a project - [real-time recognition of characters](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/cvkeyboard)

testing images are

[image: two.png]

[image: six.png]

Answer (score 0):

do you know Mnist data set is restricted with padding of images?

appropriate realtime image processing is needed.

This is useful article about that

https://link.medium.com/0ySCmyMpzU

and following is my project about simple mnist game

https://github.com/mym0404/Math-Writer

Comment: thanks MJ_Studio, Yes I know MNIST is deprecated. but It actually predicted correctly using `pillow-library`, but I think the problem is with input-image-dimensions. also I have added this details to question. BTW your project is nice.